# login to phpmyadmin on suse 13.1 fails

Tags: linux, php, javascript

' i try to login to PhpMyAdmin (on opensue 13.1 lamp) and get error: Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword) What should i do for enter to phpMyAdmin without set password? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your config.inc.php file in your phpmyadmin directory and set AllowNoPassword to true:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`